# UnknownHostException in Spring Boot with Consul

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, consul, unknown-host, spring-cloud-consul

I am using spring-boot-starter-parent version 2.2.2.RELEASE with spring-cloud.version Hoxton.SR1 to create 2 services : ordercreate(Supplier) and orderconsume(Consumer).

In Consul, the 2 services are up as below
[image]

I get the exception
**java.net.UnknownHostException: ordercreate**
when invoking the orderconsumer service as below:

**http://localhost:8282/consumeOrder**

Please find the code details below.Thanks for suggestions.

**ordercreate**

**pom.xml**

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.application.name=ordercreate
server.port=8181
```

**OrderCreateController**

```
@RestController
public class OrderCreateController {

    @GetMapping("/createOrder")
    public String createOrder() {
        System.out.println("In Supplier...");
        return "Hello consul";
    }

}
```

For Consumer,

**orderconsume**

**pom.xml**

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.application.name=orderconsume
server.port=8282
```

**OrderConsumeApplication**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class OrderConsumeApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OrderConsumeApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**OrderConsumeController**

```
@RestController
public class OrderConsumeController {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    //http://localhost:8282/consumeOrder
    @GetMapping(value="/consumeOrder")
    public String receiveOrder() {
        String uri = "http://ordercreate/createOrder";
        return restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have ribbon as a dependency?

Comment: How did you create your rest template?

Comment: @spencergibb : No I do not have ribbon dependency , should I include it ? Also the resttemplate is created as a Bean in the OrderConsumeController :                             `@Bean
    public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }`

Comment: **Solved** : Changed the consumer controller method to `@GetMapping(value="/consumeOrder")
 public String receiveOrder() {
  return restTemplate.exchange("http://ordercreate/createOrder",HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<String>() {}).getBody();
 }` , thanks to this link [https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-cloud/consul-service-registration-discovery/]

Comment: Hmm, rest template need load balanced annotation